# Automatically unmount external drives when shutting down OSX?

Tags: macos, external-disk, shutdown

I'm running OSX 10.10 Yosemite. When I try to shut it down, if I have an external drive connected the shutdown stalls on a black screen with the mouse pointer visible, and movable.

This happens even if no applications are running when I shut down, so it doesn't appear to be the case that OSX can't unmount the external drive.

One solution that came to mind would be to write a bash script that would unmount all external drives, and to run that script on shutdown. Is this a sensible solution? How do you run a script on shutdown?

Comment: Easiest way is to write a script that serves as a logout hook

Answer (score 1):

There are few apps that can eject the external drive as [described here](http://www.atpeaz.com/index.php/2013/automaticlly-eject-external-disks-on-sleep-reconnect-after-os-x/):

Automatically eject external disks on sleep and reconnect after on OS X

[Jettison app $4.99](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/jettison/id447430809?mt=12&ign-mpt=uo%3D4)

[autoEJECT app $4.99](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/autoeject/id475182187?mt=12&ign-mpt=uo%3D4)

just to name 2.